# Action method updates only 1 table MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am newbie and still learning asp.net MVC. I have created a send action method which works by sending amount of money from a user to another based on the account number and the sufficient funds. My program works just fine but whenever I try to send money from one account to another, the update works only on the Transactions table and no updates occur on the CheckingAccounts table which should deduct from the balance - in case of transfer - or add into it as required! Did I miss anything in the action method? and why didn't update the balance in the aCheckingAccounts table? Any help would be much appreciated!

Money Transfer Action Method

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult MoneyTransfer(int checkAccountId)
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MoneyTransfer(Transfers transfer)
    {
      var checkingFunds = DB.checkAccounts.Find(transfer.CheckAccountId); 
        if (checkingFunds.Balance < transfer.Amount)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Amount", "You do not have enough money!");
        }

        var checkingExistedAccount = DB.checkAccounts.Where(account => account.AccountNumber == transfer.checkingExistedAccount).FirstOrDefault();
        if (checkingExistedAccount == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("checkingExistedAccount", "Account does not exist!");
        }


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
            //transaction.TransactionDate = DateTime.Now;       
            DB.Transactions.Add(new Transaction { CheckAccountId = transfer.CheckAccountId, Amount = -transfer.Amount });
            DB.Transactions.Add(new Transaction { CheckAccountId = checkingExistedAccount.Id, Amount = transfer.Amount });
            DB.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");


        }

        return View();
    }
```

Transfer Model

```
 public class Transfers
    {
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int CheckAccountId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name ="Recipient Account ID ")]
        public string checkingExistedAccount { get; set; }
    }
```

CheckingAccount Model

```
     public class CheckingAccount
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Account Number: ")]
        public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Balance: ")]
        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        public decimal Balance { get; set; }
    }
```

Transactions Model

```
 public class Transaction
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int CheckAccountId {get; set;}
        public DateTime? TransactionDate { get; set; }
        public virtual CheckingAccount checkAccount { get; set; }
    }
```

Update: Activating the TransactionDate property throws an exception error of

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'TransactionDate', table
>   'aspnet-dbo.Transactions'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
>   The statement has been terminated

Comment: The code you pasted in your controller won't compile as you've pasted it. Do you actually have an extra `;` in your method?

Comment: Hi, There was an extra ; and removed it in the get method! Sorry Typo error!! No there ins't a ; in the method.

Comment: Are you getting any errors or exceptions?

Comment: I was when I enable the DateTime and I have to ? to make it nullable

Comment: What was the error? Could you edit your question and include it please?

Comment: Please check the edited question ? I have included the error type with the DateTime.

Comment: The column in your database isn't nullable. You'd need to update that column in the database to be nullable.

Comment: But I need the date value to be in the Transactions table with every update i.e. not nullable!

Comment: You said `"I was when I enable the DateTime and I have to ? to make it nullable"` .. Does it have to be nullable or does it not have to be?

Comment: Right, I wanted it to have the same timestamp on the Transaction table

Answer (score 1):

> "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'TransactionDate', table 'aspnet-dbo.Transactions'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails. The statement has been terminated"

This is your problem. You're not setting the `TransactionDate` on the new `Transaction` record(s) you are adding to the database. Even though your model has it as a nullable DateTime the table itself must be defined with it as non-nullable.

```
        DB.Transactions.Add(new Transaction
        {
            CheckAccountId = transfer.CheckAccountId,
            Amount = -transfer.Amount,
            TransactionDate = DateTime.Now
        });
        DB.Transactions.Add(new Transaction
        {
             CheckAccountId = checkingExistedAccount.Id,
             Amount = transfer.Amount,
             TransactionDate = DateTime.Now
        });
```

If you want the two transactions to have exactly the same timestamp then use a variable instead:

```
        var transactionDate = DateTime.Now;
        DB.Transactions.Add(new Transaction
        {
            CheckAccountId = transfer.CheckAccountId,
            Amount = -transfer.Amount,
            TransactionDate = transactionDate
        });
        DB.Transactions.Add(new Transaction
        {
             CheckAccountId = checkingExistedAccount.Id,
             Amount = transfer.Amount,
             TransactionDate = transactionDate
        });
```

As to why it's not updating the other table(s), I don't see any code in your question that's actually doing that. You will need to retrieve the checking account records and update their balances before writing the record back.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Chris. I will check the code and of course just realised that my code missing the Update on the Balance after the transfer process

Comment: Still throwing an error ! even after altering the code!

Comment: Is it throwing the same error, or a different error?

Answer (score 1):

The error says that the column TransactionDate in your database doesn't allow null value.

In Transaction class you can change `public DateTime? TransactionDate { get; set; }`
to : `public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }` so you will need to set a date when adding a transaction.

Comment: I want the date in the transactions table to have exactly the same time stamp then performing the transfer. I disabled the  ? in the transaction class and has used the same as what Chris posted but have this error: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'TransactionDate'

Comment: By the way you should put the adding lines into a try catch block.

Comment: I know but I disabled the try catch block to diagnose the program!

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Transactions] (
    [Id]              INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Amount]          DECIMAL (18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [CheckAccountId]  INT             NOT NULL,
    [TransactionDate] DATETIME        DEFAULT ('1900-01-01T00:00:00.000') NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Transactions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Transactions_dbo.CheckingAccounts_CheckAccountId] FOREIGN KEY ([CheckAccountId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[CheckingAccounts] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

Comment: Ok, it is the definition table script i guess, try change the specified part by this value `[TransactionDate] DATETIME NOT NULL`

Comment: The application works just fine now but the only remaining issue is the update on the CheckingAccount table 
I have had made a method in a class called service which updates the balance in case of transfer, withdraw, or depsoite 
The update occurs only on deducting the balance but it doesn't add the new value for the recipient balance!!

Comment: Hi did you solve your issue? Maybe you should let us see this new method which updates the balance in the Service and the error.